# is there a way to check if a class has the main method?

Tags: java, parsing, program-entry-point

I'm trying to get the list of all classes in a project in Java and I would like to identify the class where the main method is located. Is there a way to be able to identify that a class is implementing the main method, without actually looking at the code of the class itself?

I've implemented the following but the return value is always being false. does anyone know why this is happening?

```
Class<?> c = "edu.tool.parsing.A".getClass();
        boolean hasMain = true;

            try {
                c.getMethod("main", String[].class);
                hasMain=true;
            } catch (SecurityException e) {
                 hasMain = true;
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                hasMain=false;
            }
```

Comment: [Reflection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/) might help you.

Comment: Why don't you just search for 'void main' in your project with Windows or whatever operating system you use ? Looking for the method 'main' throught reflection seems a bit too much : ) Unless you want to do that oftenly to generate some kind of generic launcher.

Comment: As the variation of the answers indicate, you should include the context in your question. E.g. _where_ and _how_ are you trying to list these classes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Programmatically:

`Class.getClass("com.mycompany.MyClass").getMethod("main", String[].class)`

Or alternatively you can use command line utility `javap` that you can find in your JDK bin directory.

Comment: when i implemented it with the package and my class, the IDE that getCLass cannot be applicable for Arguments(String).. the CLass youre using here is the normal Class object right?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the class name, then you can try to reflect the `main` method.

Trivial (inclomplete) approach:

```
private static hasMainMethod(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
  Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
  for (Mehthod method:methods) {
    if (method.getName().equals("main") {
      // Now we have to verify the method signature!
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There may be more than one such class. There may be dozens. Why don't you know the entry point in advance? You might be better off looking at the Main-Class entry in the JAR Manifest.

Answer (score -1):

Load your project in a IDE (I have worked with IDEA) then, add a local run, IDEA will list you all classes with main method.

If you don't have sources and there are just jar files, that's ok, just add the jar files as a library of a project and then create a RUN.